# ggplot2: geom_smooth select observations connections (equivalence to geom_path())

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I am using `ggplot2` to create vertical profiles of the ocean. My raw data set creates "spikes" so to make smooth curves. I am hoping to use `geom_smooth()`. I also want the line to progress according to the order of the observations (and not according to the x axis). When I use `geom_path()`, it works for the original plot, but not for the resulting `geom_smooth()` (see picture below).

```
melteddf = Storfjorden %>% melt(id.vars = "Depth")
ggplot(melteddf, aes(y = Depth, x = value)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ variable, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x") + 
  scale_y_reverse() +
  geom_smooth(span = 0.5,se = FALSE) + 
  geom_path()
```

[image]
Therefore is there a way to make sure the smooth curve progress according to the order of observations, instead of the a axis?

Subset of my data:

```
head(Storfjorden)
      Depth Salinity Temperature Fluorescence
    1  0.72    34.14       3.738         0.01
    2  0.92    34.14       3.738         0.02
    3  1.10    34.13       3.739         0.03
    4  1.80    34.14       3.740         0.06
    5  2.80    34.13       3.739         0.02
    6  3.43    34.14       3.739         0.05
```

Comment: Could you include a subset of your data (using `dput` and `head`) so that this is [more reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I hope the edit I did correspond to what you were asking. Thanks!

Comment: You can try using `coord_flip` and swapping x and y, but facets tend to give some troubles with that. Otherwise you will probably have to do the smoothing outside of `ggplot` first. Have a look at `?loess`.

Comment: I did consider `loess`but then I struggle using a loess object in geom_smooth. But if you have insights using loess I will be really glad to hear about!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data that you provided is quite minimal, but we can make it work.

Using some of the tidyverse packages we can fit separate loess functions to each of the `variables`.

What we do, essentially, is

1. Group our data by `variable` (`group_by`).
2. Use `do` to fit a loess function to each group.
3. Use `augment` to create predictions from that loess model, in this case for a 1000 values within the range of the data (for that `variable`).

.

```
# Load the packages
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

lo <- melteddf %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  do(augment(
    loess(value ~ Depth, data = .), 
    newdata = data.frame(Depth = seq(min(.$Depth), max(.$Depth), l = 1000))
  ))
```

Now we can use that predicted data in a new `geom_path` call:

```
ggplot(melteddf, aes(y = Depth, x = value)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ variable, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x") + 
  scale_y_reverse() +
  geom_path(aes(col = 'raw')) +
  geom_path(data = lo, aes(x = .fitted, col = 'loess'))
```

(I map simple character vectors to the color of both lines to create a legend.)

#### Result:

[image]